# Binding default values on Picker and DatePicker when ViewModel loading

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I want to set selected date on `DatePicker` and Selected item on `Picker` when on  when `ViewModel` class loading. How I am doing it

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
    var objL = parameters.GetValue<LeaveManagement>("LeaveItem");
    SelectedFromDate = objL.StartDate;
    SelectedToDate = objL.EndDate;
    SelectedLeaveType = new SpinnerBind { Name = objL.LeaveTypeCD, Value = objL.LeaveTypeId };           
}

private DateTime? _selectedFromDate;
public DateTime? SelectedFromDate
{
    get { return _selectedFromDate; }
    set { _selectedFromDate = value; }
}
private DateTime? _selectedToDate;
public DateTime? SelectedToDate
{
    get { return _selectedToDate; }
    set { _selectedToDate = value; }
}

private ObservableCollection<SpinnerBind> _leaveType;
public ObservableCollection<SpinnerBind> LeaveType
{
    get { return _leaveType; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _leaveType, value);
    }
}
private SpinnerBind _selectedLeaveType;
public SpinnerBind SelectedLeaveType
{
    get { return _selectedLeaveType; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedLeaveType, value);
    }
}
```

This is my XAMl

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <DatePicker Format="dd/MM/yyyy"   Date="{Binding SelectedFromDate}"/>

    <DatePicker  Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Date="{Binding SelectedToDate}"/>

    <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLeaveType, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding LeaveType,Mode=TwoWay}"
            TitleColor="Black" TextColor="Black" Title="--Select--"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But all values Startdate, Enddate and SelectedLeaveType not getting set. However `Picker` is binding with `LeaveType` How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So what you want is on load of your page you want default values in Pickers and DatePickers?

Comment: Yes, on DatePicker I need to set Date and on Picker selected item when ViewModel loading, three values of  `OnNavigatedTo` method I need to bind.

Comment: And what exactly is the issue that is happening with it?

Comment: Picker is showing up with --Select-- and DatePicker is coming with today date.

Comment: Okay Let me answer this give me a minute, also are these properties in the ViewModel or a Model?

Comment: have you tried to bind the selected index too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property of a view model changes, it needs to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` to update the bindings.

Prism provides the `BindableBase` base class for view models, which has a `SetProperty` method normally used to update the backing field and raise the event if needed.

That is, you want something like this

```
public DateTime? SelectedFromDate
{
    get { return _selectedFromDate; }
    set { SetProperty( ref _selectedFromDate, value ); }
}
```

**Edit:** To bind `Picker` with default selected item, initialize `SelectedLeaveType` from the [Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6445).

Comment: in the question, there's `set { _selectedFromDate = value; }`, which obviously does not raise an event. Whereas, we have `SetProperty(ref _leaveType, value);` which is obviously superfluous, because it's an `ObservableCollection` and should have no setter at all.

Comment: Unless `SpinnerBind` defines its own equality rules, I wouldn't expect a `new`ed instance to be found in the items list... by default, one uses `ReferenceEquals`.